# $\partial \partial \partial A = \partial \partial A$ for any subset $A$!

Tags: general-topology

I hope this question is not duplicate here:
Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ be "any" subset of $X$, then
$$\partial \partial \partial A = \partial \partial A.$$
(Here, $\partial B$ denotes the boundary of the subset $B$).

My work: I started with the definition and had $\partial \partial \partial A=\partial \partial A -(\partial \partial A)^{\circ}$. Then I am trying to show that the interior $(\partial \partial A)^{\circ}$ is empty.

Any ideas? Can it be a simple argument? Mine is not. Thanks in advance.

A simpler version: [Boundary of a boundary of an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544720/boundary-of-a-boundary-of-an-open-set/4551442#4551442)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105745/boundary-operators-idempotence – also, if you can see the deleted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443404/boundary-of-the-boundary-of-a-set-is-empty

Comment: Can you not simply use that $\partial \partial S \subseteq \partial S$, where equality holds iff S has no interior, then since after applying the boundary operation twice this set really has no interior the claim follows by the above.

Comment: I think Henno Brandsma's answer in the first link from Gerry's comment settles this. After all $S=\partial A$ is closed, and Henno shows that $\partial S=\partial\partial S$, which is just what's needed here.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313028/iterated-boundary-in-a-metric-space and one of the answers of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43627/boundary-in-the-topological-space

Comment: Some define boundary as $\partial X=\bar X\setminus X^\circ$. You seem to define it differently.

Comment: Boundary is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reamark that $\partial A$ is closed for arbitrary subset $A$, since $\partial A=C_{X}A^{\mathrm{o}} \cap C_{X}(C_{X}A)^{\mathrm{o}} $,in particular  $\partial  \partial A \subset  \partial A $. Now ,suppose to the contrary that there is $x$ an interior point of $\partial  \partial A $,then there is some open subset $x\in V\subset \partial  \partial A $,but this is impossible since $\partial  \partial A \subset  \partial A $, so $V\subset \partial A $ and $x$ is boundary point of $\partial A$,so every neighboorhood of it must meet $\partial A$ and its complement.

Comment: $\partial A$ can be the whole space and what did you contradict then?

Comment: If $\partial A$ is the whole space, then $\partial \partial A=\emptyset $ !

Comment: So you deduced the boundary of $A$ has no complement?

Comment: It's a proof by Contradiction, I assumed that $\partial \partial A $ has non-empty interior, picked a point in this interior, So this point has two properties 1) it's an interior point of $\partial \partial A $, in particular it is an interior point of $\partial A$, 2)it is a boundary point of $\partial A$, so every nbd of it must meet both $\partial A$ and its complement, and this is not satisfied for the nbd $V$, So I arrived at a Contradiction, I concluded that the interior of $\partial \partial A $ must be empty.